# ValidationMessage is showing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, razor

I have a piece of Razor code like so:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("State", new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="tt-container">
            @Html.Editor("StateName", new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "StateName", @class = "form-control", @required="required" } })
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessage("StateName", "The State field is required", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

The validation message `The State field is required` is showing on page load.  I only want that message to show if that textbox is empty when a user tries to submit the form.

If I do this:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("StateName", "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Then obviously I don't see any validation message because it's empty, but when I click submit and that textbox is empty I get a validation message saying `This field is required`.

I am looking for 1 of 2 possibilities.

With the first problem, can I show that validation message after the submit button is clicked if the corresponding textbox is empty?

With the 2nd problem, can I get that error message to be more descriptive like `The State field is required`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `ValidationMessage`  helper method overload

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("StateName")
```

The validation message will be a message generated by the model validation framework in the form "The {propertyName} is required"

Comment: I know that this works but it requires strongly typed properties with the model.  What I have is just a simple textbox that when something is entered into it.. that value is binded to a hiddenfor element

Comment: `StateName` is not a strongly typed property.  Just a textbox for the user to see, but the value is binded to a strongly typed hiddenfor element

Comment: You can use the same thing with `ValidationMessage` helper method as well. Use the overload which takes the propety name. See the updated answer.

Comment: If I do that.. I don't get the property name in the error message. I just get `This field is required`

Comment: That is because you are not using a view model. How does the system know that your stateName is required ?

Comment: If you use the ValidationMessageFor helper, it will generate the correct data attribute which can be used by jQuery validate plugin as well. So you get client side validation for free